# Difficulty accessing an ArrayList in another class in the package

Tags: java, object, arraylist, scope

my Java experience is very limited and I am having problems accessing an array list in another class in a separate file in the same package.

It doesn't seem to matter where I declare the array ..it is not accessible from the other classes

my top class is like:

```
package 1st_class;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.Event.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class 1st_class {


    public void main(String[] args) 
    {
        ArrayList<Test> tests = new ArrayList<Test>(); 
        ArrayList<Score> scores = new ArrayList<Score>();

        tests = new ArrayList<Test>(); 
        scores = new ArrayList<Score>();

        MainMenu Menu1 = new MainMenu();
        Menu1.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

This only seems to recognise the arrays in this code ..I can reference they by having an instance of mainmenu in the other class and prefixing the array name with for example main.

I am confused about the scope I guess.

Comment: It's **local** variable. It's not accessible even in other methods in the *same* class. I highly recommend you to go though the [basic tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) in order to understand the very basics of the language.

Comment: Is it legal to call a class `1st_class` ?

Comment: @khelwood it is "legal" but he should check the Naming convention: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java

Comment: @tumisma Identifiers can't start with a number. `1st_class` is not a legal identifier.

Answer (score 3):

Try to write `getArrayList()` method in class you need or define it like **static**.

```
public class 1st_class {
        public static ArrayList<Test> tests = new ArrayList<Test>(); 
        public static ArrayList<Score> scores = new ArrayList<Score>();

    public void main(String[] args) 
    {
        MainMenu Menu1 = new MainMenu();
        Menu1.setVisible(true);
    }
}

public newclass {

    public newclass() {
        1st_class .tests.add(new Test);
    }

}
```

Or you can do like that:

```
 public class 1st_class {
        private ArrayList<Test> tests = new ArrayList<Test>(); 
        private ArrayList<Score> scores = new ArrayList<Score>();

    public void main(String[] args)  {

        MainMenu Menu1 = new MainMenu();
        Menu1.setVisible(true);
    }

    public ArrayList<Test> getArrayList() {
         return tests;
    }
}

public newclass {

    public newclass() {
        ArrayList<Test> temp = new 1st_class().getArrayList();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your ArrayList variables are local to your main method. In order to make them accessible to other methods/classes, you should either pass them as parameters to those methods, or you should declare them in the class level.

BTW, your main method is missing `static`.

```
public class 1st_class {

    private static ArrayList<Test> tests = new ArrayList<Test>(); 
    private static ArrayList<Score> scores = new ArrayList<Score>();

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
```

However, making them public members is usually considered bad practice in OOP. If other classes need to access them, you should declare them as private and add public methods to `1st_class` which would give other classes access to them.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a variable in a class to visible to others, it needs to be a public class field. Right now it's a block local variable, which are only visible in their current block.

Try defining them like this:

```
class Something {
    public ArrayList<Test> test = new ArrayList<Test>();
}
```

Remember if you do this that you *don't* then use them inside functions with their type in front of them, or you'll override them with local variables under the same name.

Answer (score 0):

Your list is just visibile within your main method hence its not visible to other's outside main method.

One way to expose ArrayList would be via access modifier i.e. giving publicly access to both your list like below:

```
public class StClass {//i have changed name to follow camel case. Give it meaningful name
    public static ArrayList<Test> tests = new ArrayList<Test>(); 
    public static ArrayList<Score> scores = new ArrayList<Score>();
}
```

Another way would be to expose getter/setter static method so you could access at class level like below.

```
public static ArrayList<Test> getTestList() {
     return tests;
}//and similarly for scores.
```

And then from another package, call it like:

```
StClass.tests
```

OR

```
ArrayList<Test> testList = StClass.getTestList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like this if you want to call it in another class.

```
package 1st_class;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.Event.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class 1st_class {

    public ArrayList<Test> tests = new ArrayList<Test>(); 
    public ArrayList<Score> scores = new ArrayList<Score>();

    public void main(String[] args) 
    {    
        MainMenu Menu1 = new MainMenu();
        Menu1.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Now you can access tests and scores from anywhere by calling:

```
1st_class.tests
1st_class.scores
```

As they have told you, you should create the getters/setters. If you create the getters and setters you can change the variables to private.

```
public ArrayList<Test> getTests() {
    return tests;
}

public void setTests(ArrayList<Test> tests) {
    this.tests = tests;
}

public ArrayList<Score> getScores() {
    return scores;
}

public void setScores(ArrayList<Score> scores) {
    this.scores = scores;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the problem is the scope or visibility of the variables you want to access. To access the arrays from other classes you have to create them as members of your class:

```
public class YourClass {

    public ArrayList<Test> tests = null;
    public ArrayList<Scores> scores = null;

    // I guess you forgot "static" in here
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // you are in a static context, therefore you have to instantiate the class you want to access
        YourClass myClass = new YourClass();

        // now you can access the fields from your class
        myClass.tests = new ArrayList<Test>(); 
        myClass.scores = new ArrayList<Score>();
    }

}
```

From another class in the same package you can access these fields as well:

```
public class YourOtherClass {
    public void yourMethod() {
        YourClass myClass = new YourClass();
        myClass.tests.add(new Test());

        // should be 1
        System.out.println("The list has the following size:" + myClass.tests.size());
    }
}
```

Making the fields directly accessible is generally a bad practice. You may want to take a look at [encapsulation in Java](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/encapsulation-in-java/).

Kind Regards

Florian